# Constant contact API with Next js

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-typescript, constantcontact

How can I implement constant contact API on Nextjs application

Tried to read through the documentation but only examples for PHP and java was shown

How can I use the authentication flow effectively

And create an app on the dashboard to receive just one token, how do I use that?

Answer (score 1):

**Integrating the Constant Contact API into a Next.js application involves multiple steps, and while I can't cover everything in one answer, I'll provide a high-level overview and guide you through the key steps.**

**Register Your App with Constant Contact:**

Visit the Constant Contact Developer Portal and create a new application.
Note down the API key and the client secret; you'll need them later.

**Set Up Your Next.js Application:**

Create a new Next.js application or use an existing one.

Install Axios or any HTTP client of your choice to make API calls.

```
npm install axios
```

**Authentication Flow with Constant Contact:**

**3.1 OAuth2.0 Flow (For Access and Refresh Token):**

Redirect users to the Constant Contact authorization URL:

```
https://api.cc.email/v3/idfed?client_id=YOUR_API_KEY&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI&response_type=code&scope=contact_data
```

After authorization, Constant Contact will redirect back to your specified redirect_uri with a code parameter in the URL.

**Exchange this code for an access token:**

```js
// pages/api/getAccessToken.js

import axios from 'axios';

export default async (req, res) => {
  const { code } = req.query;

  try {
    const response = await axios.post('https://idfed.constantcontact.com/as/token.oauth2', {
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      code: code,
      redirect_uri: 'YOUR_REDIRECT_URI',
      client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
      client_secret: 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET'
    });

    const { access_token, refresh_token } = response.data;

    // Store these tokens securely (maybe in a session or encrypted cookie)
    res.status(200).json({ access_token, refresh_token });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to fetch access token' });
  }
}
```

**3.2 Using Just One Token (API Key Authentication):**
If you decide to use just the API Key authentication, you can use your API key to make API calls. However, this method doesn't involve user-specific data access and is limited in its functionality.

**Making Requests to Constant Contact API:**

Once you have the access token, you can make authenticated requests:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const constantContactApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.cc.email/v3',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN`
  }
});

constantContactApi.get('/contacts').then(response => {
  console.log(response.data);
});
```

**Handling Token Expiry and Refresh:**

The access token will expire after a while, so you need to use the refresh token to get a new one:

```js
export const refreshAccessToken = async (refresh_token) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('https://idfed.constantcontact.com/as/token.oauth2', {
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      refresh_token: refresh_token,
      client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
      client_secret: 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET'
    });

    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Failed to refresh token');
  }
}
```

**Storing and Securing Tokens:**

Always store tokens securely. Using sessions or encrypted cookies is a good approach in Next.js.
Never expose your client secret or tokens in client-side code.
Implement proper error handling to deal with failed requests and token expiry.

This is a basic overview of how you can integrate Constant Contact API into a Next.js application.

Comment: i need to make a post request to the contact endpoint using api_key or secret key but I keep getting unauthorised